# How to use the type mentioned in input for creating an object?

Tags: c++, c++17

Say I have a templatized class

```cpp
template<class T>
class MyClass
{
...
}
```

Now let's say for the sake of simplicity, that the input explicitly mentions that the following data shall be of what type:
for example

```
int
1 2 3 4 5
```

or

```
float 
1.5 2.3 4.2 5.9
```

Now I want to create an object based on the type mentioned in the input
Something like

```
MyClass<type_mentioned_in_input> obj;
```

**How do I achieve this?**

Based on my lesser understanding of C++, here is what I tried:

1. Create an abstract base class for the `MyClass`
2. Mention all the member functions of `MyClass` as pure virtual functions in the abstract base class
3. Dynamically initialize an object of the base class at runtime

Clearly this method not only increases the complexity, but also fails with templates.

What should be the desired what to execute this?

Comment: What you seem to be looking for is some kind of *factory method* to create the correct type from a string.

Comment: Template parameters **must** be know at compile time.

Comment: Create a templated helper class, and specialize the expected input help/display for `float` or `int`. Though note, that expected inputs for `float` or `double` values should be well even with missing decimal point.

Comment: C++ does not have reflection and templates require compile time instantiation.  So you need to create all possible (allowed) instances of the templated class ahead of time and then use a series of `if` statements to choose the correct one.

Comment: @RichardCritten I tried the if else construct and ran into 2 problems : 1. If I initialize the object dynamically, what should be the base pointer type ? 2. If i initialize it non - dynamically, the object is bound to the scope of if block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't:

`template` are compiler time, the specific content between `< .. >` is replaced when you build, and that can not be modified runtime based on the input.

The solution to your problem (about having different types defined runtime) is to use an other mechanism, like `std::variant`.